# Changing colour of each array element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to HTML/CSS/JavaScript/Jquery/
I have an array of div tags which are represented as boxes. I would like to change the colour of the boxes when I hover over them but I am not sure how to access each div tag and change its properties.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet3.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script3.js"></script>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
        </div>
    </body>
</head>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    body 
{
    background:#000;
}
.square 
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    border:2px solid #73AD21;
    height: 2.5rem;
    width: 2.5rem;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Javascript/Jquery:

```
       $(document).ready(function() {
       for(i=0; i<16; i++) {
       $('.wrapper').append('<div class="line">');
           for(j=0; j<16; j++) {
               $('.wrapper').append('<div class="square">'+j+'</div>');
           }
       $('.wrapper').append('</div>');
   }
   /*$('.wrapper').hover(function()) {
    $(this).css("background","#F00");
   }*/
   });
```

When I add the commented lines in Javascript/Jquery section, the whole webpage becomes black.

Comment: Do you want the hover to apply to .wrapper or .square?

Comment: To .square which I think represents div tags within wrapper. I tried doing what Josh has shown and it worked. Thanks for all the help everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I add the commented lines in JavaScript/jQuery section, the whole webpage becomes black.

That's because there is a syntax error. When this occurs, none of the `.square` elements are being appended, which is exactly why you are seeing a blank page.

The [`.hover()` method](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) expects two functions as parameters (a hover-in, and hover-out callback). Therefore it seems like you want the following:

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/o5434z12/)

```
$('.wrapper .square').hover(function() {
  $(this).css("background", "#f00");
}, function() {
  $(this).css("background", "#fff")
});
```

However, you can do this with pure CSS using the [`:hover` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Ahover). You don't actually need jQuery for this.

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/hgxc8z5j/)

```
.square:hover {
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: CSS will be a better way as explained by you.

Comment: @Sahil Yep. Always avoid jQuery if it can be done with pure CSS :)

Comment: very nice explanation, I was looking for something like that doing this thing form Jquery thanks it worked for me... @Josh

Answer (score 1):

That is because you have a syntax error on this line

```
$('.wrapper').hover(function()) {
    $(this).css("background","#F00");
}
```

You are closing the hover function before you call the `$(this).css` function so the "this" that is being selected is the body. It should be:

```
$('.square').hover(function() {
    $(this).css("background","#F00");
}, function() {
    $(this).css("background","#FFF");
});
```

Comment: I didn't undo anything. I didn't even know you edited it.

Answer (score 1):

There is some syntactical error in your code on commented lines.

This is correct one

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   for(i=0; i<16; i++) {
   $('.wrapper').append('<div class="line">');
       for(j=0; j<16; j++) {
           $('.wrapper').append('<div class="square">'+j+'</div>');
       }
   $('.wrapper').append('</div>');
    }


    $('.square').hover(function() {
        $(this).css("background","#F00");
        },function(){
           $(this).css("background","#fff");

       });
   });
```

[WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jddcsc57/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Hope you want this...

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
       for(i=0; i<16; i++) {
       $('.wrapper').append('<div class="line">');
           for(j=0; j<16; j++) {
               $('.wrapper').append('<div class="square">'+j+'</div>');
           }
       $('.wrapper').append('</div>');
     }
     $('.wrapper').on('hover','.square',function() {
      $(this).css("background","#F00");
     });
   
   $('.wrapper').on('mouseleave','.square',function() {
      $(this).css("background","#FFF");
     });
   });
```

```css
body 
{
    background:#000;
}
.square 
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    border:2px solid #73AD21;
    height: 2.5rem;
    width: 2.5rem;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet3.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script3.js"></script>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
        </div>
    </body>
</head>
</html>
```